# Reg Shunting yard algorithm

Tags: algorithm

A quick question on shunting yard algorithm (in wiki) which converts an infix to prefix notation.

I was under the impression that the algorithm will detect invalid expressions as part of it's working (like 1++2), but except for mismatched parenthesis, it doesn't do much validation.

This means we should validate the infix expression in the first place before sending inputs to the algorithm, if that's the case then is this the limitation of the algorithm (to handle corner cases) or expression validation and conversion/evaluation are different ball games.

Also I couldn't find a standard expression validation algorithm through search, so I assume it's all compiler related stuff.

Comment: Ok, I got some kind of answer here, the validation happens in the postfix evaluation part - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19894989/how-do-i-properly-test-whether-my-postfix-expression-is-valid